# How to Set DesiredCapabilities for a WPF App

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, selenium, ui-automation, winappdriver

I have developed a simple WPF applicaiton. I want to do some UI automation testing on my app. I started following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@yostane/automated-ui-testing-of-a-uwp-app-using-appium-dc10d8df6631) on how to do automation using Appium and Windows Application Driver.

As a part of setting up the test environment for testing Windows Calculator app, the following lines are added to the test script :

```
protected const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = “http://127.0.0.1:4723";

DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

appCapabilities.SetCapability(“app”, “57b3a460–8843–4d84–822a-9f316274c2bf_tz6ph9wdjhqw8!App”);

IOSDriver<IOSElement> AppSession = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);
```

Looking at the 3rd line, an application identifier is provided to set DesiredCapabilities. My problem is that I have trouble finding or generating a similar app ID for my WPF application. Further down in the tutorial, author mentions:

"In the third line, we set a weird identifier for the “app” device capability. You need to replace this value with yours. It can be found the generated AppX\vs.appxrecipe file under RegisteredUserModeAppID node.

`<RegisteredUserModeAppID>57b3a460–8843–4d84–822a-9f316274c2bf_tz6ph9wdjhqw8!App</RegisteredUserModeAppID>`"

Can you tell me how this appID can be generated in Visual Studio? Also, is there other ways to set DesiredCapabilities without providing an appID? Can a GUID be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Only UWP apps have an application id, classic Windows applications can be started with the path to the executable:

```cs
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", pathToYourExecutable);
```

See also the readme of WinAppDriver:
[Testing a Classic Windows Application](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver#testing-a-classic-windows-application)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find this when you're debugging your app. 
If you debug the app and set a breakpoint at the first instance.

Then in your debug tab you should be able to view the node you're looking for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I need an specific application id. How does setting a break point will help me with getting one?

Comment: Once you have built, you should find the file you need containing the id in here - "project_directory"\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\vs.appxrecipe.

Comment: So just to give you an idea, I have solution which consists of 3 sub projects, each representing model, view and view-model for my application. Each one of these projects are stored in their separate folders under the solution folder. Now when I build my application in Debug/x86 mode, the executable for my project can be found under [Solution Folder]\ [view]\bin\Debug but AppX does not exist. My question is how to generate that?